# Writing files in the wrong path with bash

Tags: bash, backup, mkdir

In the following `bash` backup script:

```
PROJECT="testPrj"
BACKUP_DIR="~/Documents/backups/"
BACKUP_FILES="./*.sh ./*.h ./*.hpp ./*.c ./*.cc ./*.cpp ./*.md ./*.txt ./BUILD"
BACKUP_TIME=_`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M`
BACKUP_FILENAME=$BACKUP_DIR$PROJECT$BACKUP_TIME.tar.bz2

mkdir -p $BACKUP_DIR
echo "Created backup directory:" $BACKUP_DIR

echo $BACKUP_FILENAME

tar -cpjf $BACKUP_FILENAME $BACKUP_FILES
```

This is the output:

> Created backup directory: ~/Documents/backups/
>   ~/Documents/backups/testPrj_20170206_1609.tar.bz2

I get the compressed file in the wrong path. Instead of being:
   `~/Documents/backups/`

it goes in:  `\~/Documents/backups/`

This destination directory effectively exists, and it is in the local path.

Running `mkdir` on its own from the command line creates the directory in the right place.

Comment: `~` won't be expanded to your home directory when it's in quotes. Use `BACKUP_DIR=~/"Documents/backups/"`. Also, its safest to use lowercase for variable names so you don't accidentally use a variable name that has special meaning to the shell or other programs (using `$PATH` is the classic example).

Comment: You are right. If you move this comment to an answer I will accept it.

Comment: You may prefer `BACKUP_DIR="$HOME/Documents/backups/" which will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~` won't be expanded to your home directory when it's in quotes. Leave it (and the following `/`) unquoted, like this:

```
BACKUP_DIR=~/"Documents/backups/"
```

Also, it's safest to use lowercase or mixed case for variable names so you don't accidentally use a variable name that has special meaning to the shell or other programs (using `$PATH` is the classic example).